# Hibernate Bytecode Enhancement for a Groovy Project

Tags: hibernate, gradle, groovy

I'm attempting to use the [hibernate plugin](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/tooling/hibernate-gradle-plugin/src/main/groovy/org/hibernate/orm/tooling/gradle/HibernatePlugin.java) in my Spring Boot groovy project. I added the following configuration to my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        hibernateVersion = '5.3.7.Final'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.hibernate:hibernate-gradle-plugin:${hibernateVersion}")
    }
}
apply plugin: 'org.hibernate.orm'

hibernate {
    enhance {
        enableLazyInitialization=true
        enableDirtyTracking=true
    }
}
```

But I am unable to use bytecode enhanced features like lazy loading properties. I look at my decompiled groovy (I'm using `@CompileStatic`) and I see no bytecode enhancement.

Inside of the plugin, the enhancement task executes this line:

```
final Task compileTask = project.getTasks().findByName( sourceSet.getCompileJavaTaskName() );
```

which will always return `CompileJava` which will never work for me since I use `CompileGroovy`. Are there any known work arounds for this? In the meantime, I'm going to patch this for myself locally and see if this works.

Comment: That means the Hibernate Gradle plugin only supports Java compilation tasks. This looks like a good feature request candidate for the Hibernate Gradle plugin.